# Give an example of a function that is starlit but contains a point which is not a star centre

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Having trouble with this one !

I understand that it is starlit if we can draw a straight line segment to every point of the region from the star centre

Intuitively I thought that the punctured open unit disk, with radius 1 would be an example of this.

Can you give me a few examples of functions which a star lit but have a point which is not starlit ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the letter "X" (i.e., two crossing line-segments). It's starlit from its center, but every point except the crossing-point is not a star center.